# How to post XML data via a proxy in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, curl, proxy

I would like to run the following command in ruby on rails via a **proxy**:

```
  curl --request POST http://200.206.38.24:8580/my_server_path/ 
       --data-binary @test01.xml 
       --header "Content-type: Application/vnd.vizrt.payload+xml;type=element"
```

And so far I have:

```
  PROXY_URL = 'proxy.mydomain.com'
  PROXY_PORT = 3128
  PROXY_USER = 'user'
  PROXY_PASSWORD = 'pass'
  MSE_HOST = '200.206.38.24'
  MSE_PORT = 8580
  MSE_PATH = '/my_server_path/'
  xml_file = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><etc... />'


  Net::HTTP::Proxy(PROXY_URL, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASSWORD).start(MSE_HOST, MSE_PORT) do |http|
    response = http.post(MSE_PATH, xml_file, {"Content-type" => "Application/vnd.vizrt.payload+xml;type=element"})
  end
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to tests, it works fine. 
The response from http.post can be accessed via the body method. Eg: response.body